# jQuery: print all the values from multiple keys within a nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a nested array in `json` as followed:

```
var json.result= [
{"id":"0","category":"Camera","name":"600D Kit", "condition":"OK"},    
{"id":"1","category":"Camera","name":"600D Kit", "condition":"missing cap"},        
{"id":"2","category":"Camera","name":"7D Kit", "condition":"OK"}]
```

And this is what I am trying to do:

1/ Find every "name" in the array.

2/ Print the values of "id" and "category" that belongs to the "name" accordingly

Ideal result: 

equipment id = 0

category: Camera

name: 600D Kit

equipment id = 1

category: Camera

name: 600D Kit

equipment id = 2

category: Camera

name: 7D Kit

This is my attempt:

```
var equipmentName = [];
var listLength = json.result.length;
while (listLength--){
    equipmentName[listLength] = json.result[listLength].name
}
console.log(equipmentName);

var equipment = json.result.find(function(e){           
    return e.name == equipmentName;             
});
console.log("equipment id: " + equipment.id);
console.log("category: " +equipment.category);                      
console.log("name: " +equipment.name);
```

I am able to print all the values of "names" within the array, and print the "id", "category" and "name" of the first item of the array if `return e.name;`. However, once I added `return e.name == equipmentName;` , I got an error of "equipment

Comment: As per your ideal result, you just want to iterate over the array and paint the values. Is my understanding correct or there is something more to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will display all your elements to the console.

```
var result= [
 {"id":"0","category":"Camera","name":"600D Kit", "condition":"OK"},    
 {"id":"1","category":"Camera","name":"600D Kit", "condition":"missing cap"},        
 {"id":"2","category":"Camera","name":"7D Kit", "condition":"OK"}
];

result.map(function(element){  
  console.log(element.id,element.category,element.name);  
  // Element display functions here
});
```